# Song plays in only premium Spotify account

Tags: ios, spotify, libspotify, spotify-app

I am developing a iPhone application with integrating  Spotify SDK. I am facing some issue regarding premium account  and simple account.

I am trying to play song with Spotify simple account without any premium account, but  it always showing an error : "The operation failed due to an unspecified issue." and after same song play with premium account they play the song.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spotify API only supports music playback for users with a Premium Subscription, although the error you're getting could more helpful but this is the reason for the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: is there any way to change the BPM of Spotify song. do have any idea?